# Why does psychopy.visual.TextStim not render text when I set pos=[50,0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, psychopy

I would like to render text on to the right side of a visual.Window using visual.TextStim. When I set the position of the TextStim to 0:

```
my_text = visual.TextStim(win, pos=[0,0])
```

The text appears on-screen. But when I change this to:

```
my_text = visual.TextStim(win, pos=[50,0])
```

for example. The text does not appear. I have tried this using python 3.6, psychopy 1.90.2. How can I use TextStim to display text stimuli to the right of the visual.Window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you haven't specified the units for the stimulus:

`my_text = visual.TextStim(win, pos=[50,0], units='pix')`

`my_text = visual.TextStim(win, pos=[0.5,0], units='norm')`

You probably used default units of 'norm' and the text rendered 50 screen-widths to the right!

Answer (score 3):

While other stimuli in psychopy take pixel-wise position references, such as MovieStim3:

```
mov = visual.MovieStim3(win, glob_vid_path, flipVert=False, flipHoriz=False, pos=(-400, 0))
```

TextStim does not. Rather the horizontal and vertical reference points are from -1 to 1 corresponding to the left and right (or top and bottom) of the screen. As such, one may position text stimuli to the right of the screen using this for example:

```
my_text = visual.TextStim(win, pos=[0.5,0])
```

EDIT:
From the comment on this answer and the other correct answer, I see that the units can be explicitly changed.

Comment: Actually the TextStim can take whatever units you choose to specify (norm, height, deg, pix, cm, etc). The issue here is likely that (as you identify), the OP thinks they are dealing with pixels but the stimulus is using (or inheriting) normalised coordinates. The issue would disappear if the units are explicitly specified.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to acknowledge what you and the other answer have said. Thank you